# How to get the props to update in redux using a variable outside `return`?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm using React and Redux to build a website and I have the code below for `AppInfo` component. I have `result` variable in the `render` method which is initialized before return statement. At first the `result` is an empty string but once the state changes it is set to an object which contains various app attributes. I want to display the `result` variable inside a `div`. The `result` always stays an empty string although I do see that the redux state is updated. In addition if call directly `this.props.appId` inside the `div` the updated state is indeed displayed. Why the result variable doesn't work?

This is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import classnames from 'classnames';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class AppInfo extends Component {

  render() {
    const { appInfo } = this.props;
    const { appId } = appInfo;
    let result = '';

    if (appId) {
      result = JSON.stringify(appInfo);
    }

    return (
      <div>
        {result}
        {`JSON.stringify(appInfo) = ${JSON.stringify(appInfo)}`}
        {`this.props = ${JSON.stringify(this.props.appInfo)}`}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

AppInfo.propTypes = {
  appInfo: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  appInfo: state.app
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(AppInfo);
```

Comment: What does the appInfo object look like? Do you have a property called appId inside that object? You say that if you call this.props.appId you get the desired result but I don't see that is possible as you don't have a prop that is named appId. Or do you have that also? 

It is probably something wrong with the appId destructuring and the if statement that checks for appId to be true.

Comment: The problem was indeed with incorrect destructuring

Comment: What does your reducer look like?

Comment: Glad to hear that it worked out!

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to use `result = JSON.stringify(this.props.appInfo);`?

I think the issue might be related to the first 2 const’s you create.